# Laravel 6 with Bootstrap Toggle and toggle-event do not work with jQuery

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, toggle, laravel-6

I followed the entire [Bootstrap Toggle](https://gitbrent.github.io/bootstrap4-toggle/) documentation, but the action still not working inside jQuery at my Laravel 6 blade file.

Deleting the `data-toggle="toggle"` from the HTML, the action works.

Looks like something is ignoring or overwriting the data-toggle event.

I already tried to use `.toggle-event` declaring the `class="toggle-event"` instead, but no success too.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#toggle-event').change(function() {
    console.log(Date());
  });
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/gitbrent/bootstrap4-toggle@3.6.1/js/bootstrap4-toggle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/gitbrent/bootstrap4-toggle@3.6.1/css/bootstrap4-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input id="toggle-event" type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-size="small" data-on="Enabled" data-off="Disabled" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger" data-id="1">
```

Answer (score 1):

I gave up using Bootstrap Toggle with Laravel 6, and then I tried the same result using [Switchery](https://abpetkov.github.io/switchery/) and it worked in the first try!

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/switchery/0.8.2/switchery.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/switchery/0.8.2/switchery.min.js"></script>
```

And  this:

```
<input name="status" type="checkbox" class="js-switch" data-id="{{$system->id}}" {{ $system->active ? 'checked' : '' }}>
```